# What Amazon REST API do I use to get book information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest

What Amazon REST API do I use to get book information? I will be using PHP.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you know the book's ID, use [ItemLookup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html). If you don't know it, use [ItemSearch](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html).

Comment: Does anyone have these links updated?